# IMU frame to body frame

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, calculus, rigid-body-dynamics

I am thinking about this problem:
My IMU is centered at point **O**, and my structural body is centered at point **p**. Points **O** and **P** are two points on a rigid body. Point P is always moving and its motion/kinematics are known. Namely, the IMU (**O**) has its own *xyz* Cartesian system, and its linear accelerations along *x, y,* and *z,* and and angular velocities around *x, y,* and *z* are reported periodically.

I am facing the problem of deriving the linear acceleration of point **P** based on motion of **O**.

[image: O and P are two points on a rigid body]

It seems that acceleration of point **P** should be represented relative to point **O**, and point **P**'s acceleration should be:

$\alpha_{p} = \alpha_o + \alpha_{po}OP + \omega_{po}\times(\omega_{po}\times OP )$

where $\alpha_o$ is the linear acceleration of point **O**, $\alpha_{po}$ is the angular acceleration of **P** relative to **O**, and $OP$ is the vector/arm from **O** to **P**, and $\omega_{po}$ is the angular velocity of point **P** relative to point **O**.

I'd like to know:

1. How do I know $\alpha_{po}$ and $\omega_{po?}$, and
2. How is this equation derived?

Some references would be really helpful. Thanks a lot!